# Hibernate issue. Works fine in SQL Dev but not in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, pivot

```
            return em.createQuery("""
            select priority, Tube, Shelf, Snd, Notion FROM (
             select c.id, CASE WHEN c.priority between 1 and 10 then '1-10'
                            WHEN c.priority between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
                            WHEN c.priority between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
                            WHEN c.priority between 31 and 40 then '31-40'
                            WHEN c.priority between 41 and 50 then '41-50'
                            WHEN c.priority between 51 and 60 then '51-60'
                            WHEN c.priority between 61 and 70 then '61-70'
                            WHEN c.priority between 71 and 80 then '71-80'
                            WHEN c.priority between 81 and 90 then '81-90'
        WHEN c.priority between 91 and 100 then '91-100' end as Priority,
             s.description
          from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, SkillTypeEntity t
           where t.id=6 and t.id=s.skillType and c.skill=s.id )
            Pivot
                (
                        count(id) for description in ('Shelf Count' as Shelf, 'Notion Count' as Notion, 'Tube Count' as Tube, '2nd Count' as Snd)
                )
            Order by 1 """).getResultList()
```

The SQL query works fine on SQL developer when I run my SQL. But the same SQL query throwing this error in Hibernate. Below is the error.

ERROR begins here ***

In the Exception org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: (
 near line 2, column 80 [

```
            select priority, Tube, Shelf, Snd, Notion FROM (
            select c.id, CASE WHEN c.priority between 1 and 10 then '1-10'
             WHEN c.priority between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
             WHEN c.priority between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
             WHEN c.priority between 31 and 40 then '31-40'
             WHEN c.priority between 41 and 50 then '41-50'
             WHEN c.priority between 51 and 60 then '51-60'
             WHEN c.priority between 61 and 70 then '61-70'
             WHEN c.priority between 71 and 80 then '71-80'
             WHEN c.priority between 81 and 90 then '81-90'
             WHEN c.priority between 91 and 100 then '91-100' end as Priority,s.description
        from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, SkillTypeEntity t
        where t.id=6 and t.id=s.skillType and c.skill=s.id )
            Pivot
                (
               count(id) for description in ('Shelf Count' as Shelf
```

, 'Notion Count' as Notion, 'Tube Count' as Tube, '2nd Count' as Snd)
                    )
                Order by 1 ]

ERROR msg ends here ****

Can someone help?

Comment: For the same reason that if you try to compile a C program with a Java compiler, that won't work. HQL and SQL are not the same language.

Comment: I changed the query to this and now it works as expected.return select CASE WHEN c.priority between 1 and 10 then '1-10' 
  end as Priority
,SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN s.description = 'Shelf Count' then 1 else 0 end,0)) as Shelf
,SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN s.description = 'Notion Count' then 1 else 0 end,0)) as Notion
,SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN s.description = 'Tube Count' then 1 else 0 end,0)) as Tube
,SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN s.description = '2nd Count' then 1 else 0 end,0)) as Snd
from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, SkillTypeEntity t
where t.id=6
Group BY CASE WHEN c.priority between 1 and 10 then '1-10'